# Eclipse RCP add entry in LogView without console print

Tags: java, logging, eclipse-rcp

I would like to add logs line in the "Error Log" view without printing those logs in the console, this because I want to manage the console log through log4j.

The idea is to use create a custom logger that:

1. Print the log in the console using log4j
2. Print the log in the "Error Log" view using Eclipse RCP features
3. Eventually show an error dialog to the user

I don't want the Eclipse RCP console log  because in this case I'd have doubled logs in the console.

How can I add entries in "Error Log" View without print them in the console?

---UPDATE

With the console output i mean the messages formatted in this manner:

```
!ENTRY com.plugin.id 4 0 2014-10-15 11:37:04.314
!MESSAGE Error Messge

!STACK 0
---stack trace
```

I don't want to see these messages in the Console output but i only want to see the entry in the LogView:

[image]

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: How can I add entries in "Error Log" View without print them in the console?

Comment: Eclipse log entries always have at least the !ENTRY and !MESSAGE lines.

Comment: So it's impossible to add a log entry only in the Log View (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-error_log_view.htm) and not in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Eclipse `ILog` interface to write to the Eclipse log.

If your plugin has an Activator derived from `Plugin` (or `AbstractUIPlugin`) you can get the log using

```
Plugin.getLog();
```

You can also use

```
ILog log = Platform.getLog(bundle);
```

where `bundle` is your plugin `Bundle` - you can get this with:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

Once you have the `ILog` use

```
IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, "plugin id", error code, "Message", throwable);

log.log(status);
```

`Status` has several constructors of varying complexity, I have show the most general.

For an Eclipse e4 application you can also use `StatusReporter`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in this way I'll have the log both in the console and in Log View. What I would want is have the log only in the Log View because Log4j provides the console log.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what you are saying. `ILog` only writes to the Eclipse error log.